# Routes generated paths have stopped working

Tags: path, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm creating a blog using `Rails 3.2.5` and have been using `link_to`'s to each action using the resource paths generated by Routes (i.e. for my `code_entries`: `code_entries_path`, `new_code_entry_path`, etc.) throughout the site.  All of a sudden whenever I try to access a page I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `controller' for #<CodeEntriesController:0x007f887f8b3300>
```

This error is from my `index` action on my `code_entries_controller.rb`, but no matter which action I try to go to in any controller I get this error on every `link_to` with a Routes resource path.  It was working fine before and I'm not sure what would have caused this.

Since this question is in the context of my `code_entries`, here is the code for `code_entries_controller.rb`, `/code_entries/index.html.haml`, `routes.rb` and the error I've been getting but in the context of the action `code_entries#index`:

---

## `code_entries_controller.rb`

---

```
class CodeEntriesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_action

  def index
    @entries = CodeEntry.order("created_at desc")
  end

  def new
    @entry = CodeEntry.new
  end

  def show
    @entry = CodeEntry.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @entry = CodeEntry.new(params[:code_entry])

    if @entry.save
      redirect_to code_entry_path(@entry), :notice => "#{@entry.title} has been created"
    else
      puts @entry.errors.messages.inspect
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @entry = CodeEntry.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @entry = CodeEntry.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if @entry.update_attributes(params[:code_entry])
      redirect_to code_entry_path(@entry), :notice => "#{@entry.title} has been updated"
    else
      puts @entry.errors.messages.inspect
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @entry = CodeEntry.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @entry.destroy
    redirect_to code_entries_path, :notice => "#{@entry.title} has been deleted"
  end
end
```

---

---

## `/code_entries/index.html.haml`

---

```
%h1 Hello!
%br
- @entries.each do |e|
  %h2= link_to e.title, code_entry_path(e)
  %h3= e.updated_at
  = raw excerpt(e, 200)
  %br
  - if current_user
    = link_to "Edit", edit_code_entry_path(e)
    = button_to "Delete", code_entry_path(e), :confirm => "Really really?", :method => :delete
  %hr
```

---

---

## `routes.rb`

---

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :code_entries
  resources :food_entries
  resources :inclusive_entries
  resources :sessions

  root :to => "home#index"

  get "login" => "sessions#new", :as => "login"
  get "logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"

  get "users/new"
end
```

---

---

## `NameError in Code_entries#index`

---

Showing /Users/kyle/Projects/blog/app/views/code_entries/index.html.haml where line #4 raised:

```
undefined local variable or method `controller' for #<CodeEntriesController:0x007f887f813418>
```

Extracted source (around line #4):

```
1: %h1 Hello!
2: %br
3: - @entries.each do |e|
4:   %h2= link_to e.title, code_entry_path(e)
5:   %h3= e.updated_at
6:   = raw excerpt(e, 200)
7:   %br
Rails.root: /Users/kyle/Projects/blog
```

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

```
app/views/code_entries/index.html.haml:4:in `block in _app_views_code_entries_index_html_haml___3334012984247114074_70112115764360'
app/views/code_entries/index.html.haml:3:in `_app_views_code_entries_index_html_haml___3334012984247114074_70112115764360'
Request
```

Parameters:

```
None
```

Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

```
None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had made a method inside of `application_controller.rb` and used it as an argument with `helper_method`.  Since it was inside of `application_controller.rb` and not `application_helper.rb` I had used the tag `include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` so I could use a `link_to` inside the helper method.  Somehow that `include` statement was making it blow up, but once I removed the `include` statement and moved the helper method into `application_helper.rb` everything turned out fine!